# Music stops on moving to another activity, while using background service to play music

Tags: java, android, android-activity, service

I'm developing a game, I have used services to play music on all activities.
I want to stop the music when we hit the home key, it shouldn't stop playing music when moving from one activity to another.

```
public class backService extends Service {
private MediaPlayer mp;
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mp.stop();
    mp.release();
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.all);
    mp.setLooping(true);
    mp.start();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
    }
```

and my main activity file

```
public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {
private AdView mAdView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    hide();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    Intent i = new Intent(this, backService.class);
    adv();
}



@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    Intent i = new Intent(this, backService.class);
    startService(i);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Intent i = new Intent(this, backService.class);
    stopService(i);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    Intent i = new Intent(this, backService.class);
    stopService(i);
}
    }
```

How can I stop the music when I hit the home key and keep playing the music when we switch between other activities
TIA

Comment: what is the current behavior of your app when testing it?

Comment: Use a base activity and extend it to all activities , there u can initilalize the service class once and stop using home button pressed listener

Answer (score 1):

Please remove the  **stopService(i)** inside **onStop()** method in Activity coz whenever you are going one **Activity to Another Activity** then **onStop()** method will be called, that's why your service is killing.

If you want to pause or stop music while press home button then implements **ComponentCallbacks2** interface to **Activity** like this

```
 @Override
public void onTrimMemory(final int level) {
    if (level == ComponentCallbacks2.TRIM_MEMORY_UI_HIDDEN) {
        if(mService != null){
            mService.pauseMusic();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it worked, when i hit home the music stops and it wont stop when i go to other activities, but there is a problem. The music wont resume when i come back to app after pressing home.

Comment: You have to handle that, mean bind your service to Activity and handle all data

Answer (score 0):

Try to stop the service in

```
@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    // Check if app is in foreground
    if(!isAppOnForeground(context))
    {
        stop music here 
     }
}
```

below is the method to check if the app is in foreground or not . just replace your package here `"your package name here";`

```
public static boolean isAppOnForeground(Context context)
{
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> appProcesses = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
if (appProcesses == null) {
return false;
}
final String packageName = "your package name here";
for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo appProcess : appProcesses) {
if (appProcess.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND && appProcess.processName.equals(packageName)) {
return true;
}
}
return false;
}
```

Comment: I tried,
same it still stops when I go to another activity.

Comment: Edited my answer , please check